# Where is the extra hour? Eurostar London to Paris is 2hr 30m but departure is 3hrs 30m before arrival

Tags: eurostar, timezones, timetables

I'm trying to book the Eurostar from London to Paris.

It says the trip takes around 2hrs 30mins.
But the departure time and arrival times differ by about 3hrs 30mins.

Where did my hour go?

[image: eurostar ticket quotes]

Comment: Local time differs in departure and destination. France is in a time zone that's one hour ahead of the UK

Comment: My first thought when I saw this in the hot network questions was daylight savings time being observed in the middle of the flight. But then I found out it is yet to be observed in France, whereas it was observed over the weekend here in most of North America.

Comment: @CaveJohnson The EU synchronized DST/Summer Time dates in 1995 and the UK hasn't changed away, yet. Similarly, the US de-facto sets the dates for Canada and Northern Mexico, though the last time it took a few cycles to propagate.

Comment: @user71659 that's surprising they set it for Canada and Mexico, since they don't even set it for Arizona!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica daylight saving time is full of surprises.

Comment: @phoog ... all of them unpleasant.

Comment: Just a fun little example why programmers hate times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: Now that we settled the time zone difference, have a look at the prices. The fastest train is the cheapest. Who can explain that?

Comment: @john95 Completely unrelated to your question and I don't want to scare you but I've heard horror stories recently about the time it has taken to pass immigration before boarding the train, and that the train doesn't wait if some passengers are stuck getting through immigration. Allow plenty of time!

Comment: @Rich and others... Thanks/Merci.  When I asked, I thought maybe they already added an extra hour for clearing ticketing and customs, and maybe (Ha-ha), I did not need to arrive any "earlier". Not at all... I do need to arrive an hour, or more, earlier than the departure time.  I had completely overlooked timezones.  Thanks again.

Comment: an easy way to think about it: `Departs 07:55 UTC+0` and arrives `10:27 UTC+0`

Comment: You probably have not tried yet to book Paris to London! (Edit: this COULD BE an answer, couldn't it?)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Arizona is something of a patchwork when it comes to DST.  While most of the state does not change their time twice a year, the Navajo Reservation does, but not the Hopi Reservation which is inside the Navajo.  Not sure about the other Reservations, which form a large percentage of the state...

Comment: @Morten probably because it runs at an hour that's typically not getting a lot of sales

Answer (score 92, accepted):

France is in a different timezone, one hour ahead of the UK (CET to GMT in winter, CEST to BST in summer). All the times shown are in the local time for that station.

Comment: [A story about timezones and airplane flights.](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialRFDTV/videos/jw-lb-storytime-cajun-flying-from-atl-to-msy/330511262049556/)